# If there is a set that is finite for a countably additive function then f(phi) is zero ie the function is a measure.

Tags: measure-theory

This is a question from Donald Cohn's Measure Theory.

Let (X,$\Omega$) be a measurable space

a.) Suppose $\mu$ is a non negative countably additive function on $\Omega$. Show that if $\mu(A)$ is finite for some set A in $\Omega$, then $\mu(\phi)=0$.

So I tried to construct a sequence of sets such that their intersection is $\phi$ using the set with finite measure but I can't find one. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

Use this fact:  $A\cup \emptyset = A$ is a disjoint union.

Comment: oh wow that was easy. I feel a little stupid now haha! Thank you for answering though :)